# Wrong Resource File SharePoint 2010

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, web-part

When editing (already existing) pages users are getting an unexpected error which in logs shows that the file:

> C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\Resources\filename.en-US.resx

Cannot be found. The only file we have on our servers however is:

> C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\Resources\filename.resx

We don't appear to have any localised version of these files. And the issue isn't happening on newly made sites.

I read somewhere web parts were having issues with the **KB284486** patch.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Is it sub site where you get file not found exception?

Comment: @VirajGorajia It's happening on all sites/subsites that were made. New sites don't seem to have the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

If possible try putting the resource files in `

> C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories(SharePoint
>   Site)Port\App_GlobalResources

`

(SharePoint site)Port should be the virtual directory where you are deploying to solution

Try following commands with command prompt

> cd /d "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server
>   Extensions\14\Resources"
>
> copy filename.resx filename.en-US.resx

Comment: Resource files are already in that location. I just need to update the existing sites resource files so that it points to filename.resx instead of filename.en-US.resx

Comment: Have you added file in 14 hive?

Comment: Yes it's already there.

Comment: Have you checked the name of file?

Comment: The file hasn't been changed, its a custom file that we made and had been working fine until now. It's looking for a localized version of the file.

Comment: Hope this link will helpful you http://onlinecoder.blogspot.in/2012/04/sharepoint-global-resource-file.html

Comment: No - I don't need to add/change resource files I need to change what resource file existing sites are trying to open.

Comment: Have already tried copying the files but doesn't work.

Comment: Have you tried with this command? Copy paste en-us.resx file to 14\CONFIG\Resources location also.

Comment: Yes, have also tried that - copied the file to all 6 of our servers in all locations.